# AWK: trying to find instances of a value in a column; awk returning instances of Nan as well as value

Tags: if-statement, awk, nan

I'm having a very frustrating problem using AWK and have been unable to find a solution here.
It (should be!) very simple:

I have a text file 'myfile.txt' containing 3 columns. Contents are:

```
-101.358 80.775 3
-100.187 80.850 2
-98.019 80.976 NaN
-96.476 81.0566 NaN
```

All I want to do is retrieve instances where column 3 = 3. So I do:

`awk '{if ($3 == 3) print $1, $2, $3}' myfile.txt`

Returns:

```
-101.358 80.775 3
-98.019 80.976 NaN
-96.476 81.0566 NaN
```

For some reason it is returning NaNs as well as the 3 I'm looking for.
I get the same result with:

`awk '$3 == 3 {print $1, $2, $3}' myfile.txt`

Returns:

```
-101.358 80.775 3
-98.019 80.976 NaN
-96.476 81.0566 NaN
```

I can overcome the problem by doing:

`awk '{if ($3 == 3 && $3 != nan) print $1, $2, $3}' myfile.txt`

Returns:

```
-101.358 80.775 3
```

But it is a pain to have to include this extra condition every time I use awk to find instances of some value in my files.

Please help!
I'm running version 20070501.

Many thanks

Comment: cannot be reproduced here. `awk '$3==3'` gives what you want.

Comment: I have solved the problem by installing gawk on a colleagues recommendation. I believe I was using a buggy old version of awk. Thanks

Comment: In any case, `awk '$3==3' file` is the command you want. Everything else is superfluous because printing the whole line is the default action of awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to do numeric comparisons with values that are not numbers using an awk that supports the case-independent `nan` notation (and presumably `inf` too) and getting undesirable results.

Normally all awk values are numbers or strings. `nan` is special (in some awks) as it's neither and so awk or the underlying C primitives it uses has to decide what to do with it.

When comparing any number to `nan` the most sensible choice would be to always result in "fail" since no number CAN be equal to (nor less than nor greater than)  `nan` but apparently some awk providers decided not to do that as you've discovered. I personally would consider that a bug but I don't know enough about number theory or the history of standards around the uses of `nan`s to say if it is or not. Shrug.

Without the `--posix` flag gawk will treat `nan` as a string but will treat `+nan` and `-nan` as "special" numeric values. With `--posix` gawk will treat `nan` as whatever the underlying `C` primitives decide it is on the system you're running on. Those decisions are to support historical programs and will vary from system to system.

So though you think gawk without `--posix` is working for you now because `$3==3` is false when the input is `NaN`, it actually isn't, it's just converting the string `NaN` to `0` for the numerical comparison.

The portable solution to your problem then is - don't do that. If your input data can contain `nan`s then write your code to handle them however you want them handled, e.g.:

```
$ awk '$3!="NaN" && $3==3' file
-101.358 80.775 3
```

but `gawk --posix` will do what you want with your existing data:

```
$ gawk '$3==3' file
-101.358 80.775 3

$ gawk --posix '$3==3' file
-101.358 80.775 3

$ echo '1 2 NaN' | gawk '$3+0==0'
1 2 NaN

$ echo '1 2 NaN' | gawk --posix '$3+0==0'
$
```

and wrt being able to perform arithmetic on `nans` and have the result also be a `nan` as mentioned in your comments, that also requires `gawk --posix` with your data:

```
$ gawk '{print $2 - $3}' file
77.775
78.85
80.976
81.0566

$ gawk --posix '{print $2 - $3}' file
77.775
78.85
nan
nan
```

So it sounds like `gawk --posix` will provide all the behavior you want from the data that you have but beware that the usual truncation rules for converting strings that look like numbers to numbers applies so if you have an input string that starts with whatever awk considers a `nan` then it will get mapped to `nan` when used in a numeric context instead of converted to zero:

```
$ echo 'nanny' | gawk '{ print $1 + 0 }'
0

$ echo '+nannny' | gawk '{ print $1 + 0 }'
nan

$ echo 'nanny' | gawk --posix '{ print $1 + 0 }'
nan
```

Also be aware that using gawk in POSIX mode strips it of all of it's useful extensions like `gensub()` so the better approach might be to prefix your `nan`s with `+`s so gawk can recognize them as `nan`s without requiring the `--posix` handicap and without thinking you meant `nan` when you wrote `nanny` (see above):

```
$ echo 'nan' | gawk '{print ($1+0==0)}'
1

$ echo 'nan' | gawk --posix '{print ($1+0==0)}'
0

$ echo '+nan' | gawk '{print ($1+0==0)}'
0

$ echo '+nan' | gawk --posix '{print ($1+0==0)}'
0

$ echo '+nan' | gawk '{print ($1+0==0), gensub(/foo/,"bar",1)}'
0 +nan

$ echo '+nan' | gawk --posix '{print ($1+0==0), gensub(/foo/,"bar",1)}'
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp constant for parameter #1 yields boolean value
gawk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: function `gensub' not defined

$ cat file
-101.358 80.775 3
-100.187 80.850 2
-98.019 80.976 +NaN
-96.476 81.0566 +NaN

$ gawk '{print $2 - $3}' file
77.775
78.85
nan
nan
```

So in summary - while `gawk --posix` will work with your current data, I'd recommend changing your data to use `+NaN` instead of `NaN` so it works in gawk without `--posix` so you have access to gawks many incredibly useful extensions and you don't unexpectedly get strings that start with `nan` (e.g. `nanny`) converted to `nan`.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response Ed - very helpful. It looks like posix will indeed solve my problem. There was as you say a typo in my original question, I have since corrected it. Apologies for this!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, adding `--posix` will work with your data today but I'd recommend changing your data to use `+NaN` instead of `NaN` so it works in gawk without `--posix` so you have access to gawks many incredibly useful extensions.